# Spotfire Calculated Column on Dates

Tags: calculated-columns, spotfire

[image]

I have the above dataset.I need to create new column "JoinDate"
If "Rank" is 1, the new column "JoinDate" should get the value of "Date" of the row having "Rank"=1 and place the value in the JoinDate,else it should get the previous value of "JoinDate". Please check the below Requested table.

Essentially I want to implement something like : First(Date) over ([ID])

[image]

I know we cannot use the new column even before its created but is there anyway to achieve this.Dont want to use TERR!

Answer (score 0):

The formula you are looking for isn't `First()`, it's `Min()`

- `Min([Date]) over ([ID]) as [JoinDate]`

**RESUTLS**

```
+----+------------+------+------------+
| ID |    Date    | Rank |  JoinDate  |
+----+------------+------+------------+
|  1 | 01/01/2007 |    1 | 01/01/2007 |
|  1 | 01/01/2007 |    2 | 01/01/2007 |
|  1 | 01/02/2007 |    3 | 01/01/2007 |
|  1 | 01/03/2007 |    4 | 01/01/2007 |
|  1 | 01/03/2007 |    5 | 01/01/2007 |
|  2 | 01/01/2008 |    1 | 01/01/2008 |
|  2 | 01/01/2008 |    2 | 01/01/2008 |
|  2 | 01/02/2008 |    3 | 01/01/2008 |
|  2 | 01/02/2008 |    4 | 01/01/2008 |
+----+------------+------+------------+
```